# Poetic metre of 'Three Little Birds'

Tags: poetry, meter

I'm trying to understand how poetic feet and meter apply in different contexts, particularly lyrics. When considering this, the majority of the texts which I read seem to assume that meter is fairly uniform throughout. So Iambic pentameter, for example, sees each foot represent a pair of syllables with the second syllable stressed and five feet per line.

I'm coming across quite a few non-uniform instances and I would be grateful if someone could help me understand how this translates into poetry. I'm using three little birds as an example, because it's well known. I've also written a poem below as an example to demonstrate a non-musical instance.

Both examples see an odd number of syllables for more than one line. There's also no simple pattern for which syllable is stressed.

Can somebody help me understand how meter applies in these use cases? Or am I trying to fit a square peg into a round hole?

---

Example 1: Three little birds

> Woke up this mornin'
>
> Smiled at the rising sun
>
> Three little birds
>
> Perched by my doorstep
>
> Singing sweet songs
>
> With melodies pure and true
>
> Singing: 'this is my message to you-ou-ou'

---

Example 2: Where did my tea go?

> I made my dog a cup of tea
>
> And placed it in her bowl
>
> I made one for her and one for me
>
> But my doggies drank it all

Comment: I don't know your second example, but I think you probably *are* trying to fit square pegs into round holes here. Even with *Three Little Birds*, I expect different singers (including Bob Marley himself, on different occasions) might vary the stress patterns and syllabic divisions (to suit their mood and/or the backing instrumentation). *Limericks* and some types of *doggerel* , for example, usually have an *extremely* rigid stress pattern. But poetry / songs in general aren't always particularly fixed in that respect.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @fumblefingers. I'll add some further context. The second example was one I threw together myself for this question. I agree that its not always necessary (or desirable) to follow a strict stress pattern, but I'm trying to get my head around how the more obscure patterns are classified. I'm open to the possibility that I'm being overly scientific about this, but would find it surprising to find that this level of categorisation hasn't already been considered given how common this form of writing is.

Comment: Well, a *long* time ago I studied Eng Lit to degree level. I know we sometimes had reason to refer to "blank verse" and "half-rhymes" in the context of "poetry" (clear-cut "metre" but vague or non-existent rhyme). I can't really see why anyone would even have *wanted* a specialised term for "half-metres" (or whatever *exactly* you have in mind here). But it sounds (pun intended! :) like something more relevant to lyricists and musicians in general, rather than a matter of "language" as such. Except if there really is a ***name*** for the relevant phenomenon.

Comment: Poetic meter (as we USAns write) is more like traffic signals and road signs in Malaysia -- more of a suggestion than a rule. Breaking metric rules is part of poetic license, as are half-rhymes, without which there'd be little rock music.

Comment: All great answers, thank you. I know that there's a half-meter name for some forms of Iambic poetry (Choliambic). Are there others? Is there such a thing as "Choltrochaic", for example?

Comment: The Wiki article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry)) is a good starting point. As it has been acknowledged that entirely regular metre is rare, there is scope for analysing individual lines (or pairs, etc) and using combinations of terms. You should then search for these terms to see that you have not "invented a word."